# How To Check whether Type is the subtype

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Types:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE foo AS OBJECT (
  name VARCHAR2(45)
NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bar UNDER foo(
    additional_column NUMBER(10,2)
    )
FINAL;
```

and a Table referencing `foo`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE baz (
  id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  foo foo,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

I want to create a function in which I need to check whether the current row contains the Subtype `bar`.

I have the following Code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction() RETURN NUMBER IS
    CURSOR lookup_table
    IS
        SELECT * FROM baz;

    rec_lookup lookup_table%ROWTYPE;
    number_bar NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
    OPEN lookup_table;
    LOOP
        FETCH lookup_table INTO rec_lookup;
        EXIT WHEN lookup_table%NOTFOUND;
         number_bar := TREAT(rec_lookup.bar as BAR).additional_column;
    end loop;
    CLOSE lookup_table;
    
    RETURN number_bar;
end;
```

So far this works, but whenever a row contains the type `Foo` it'll crash.
So I thought about encapuslating the `TREAT` in an `IF`-Statement where I check whetether the current Type is `BAR`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Needed to change my select Statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM baz WHERE foo IS OF (bar);
```